# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel function

Tags: opencl

Please correct me if I am wrong in understanding.

```
err= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,kernel,1,NULL,global,wg,0,NULL,&gpuExec);
```

**Is CPU code (written between these two function) execute at same time on CPU, when kernel executing on GPU ....means they execute simultaneously
?**

```
err=clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,output,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_int)*100,results,0,NULL,NULL);
```

2) this function

```
err= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,kernel,1,NULL,global,wg,0,NULL,&gpuExec);
```

return immediately and CPU can do another work after this function call(means after that kernel starts executing on GPU on differents core) and at the same time when kernel is executing ,CPU can do its another work ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your questions can be answered with *yes*. Kernels are executed asynchronously on the GPU, therefore you can do other work on the CPU in the mean time. You could wait explicitly on your `gpuExec` event using `clWaitForEvents(1, &gpuExec)` though.

Comment: but i should use clflush or clfinish after ndqueuerangekernel

Comment: No you don't have to. First of all, `clFlush` merely guarantees that commands will be submitted to the devices. Second, blocking commands (such as your read) implicitly flush the queue. `clFinish` on the other hand, is usually used as a blocking barrier which will be crossed once all commands are finished. Unfortunately, some details are left for the implementation to be decided.

Comment: One more thing: You should issue `clFlush` if you pushed the commands to different queues. However, as I can see from your example, you are using only one command queue.

Comment: and if i dont use anything after ndqueuerangekernel then what will be taken by default by the program, clfinish or clflush

Comment: and if use only ndqueuerangekernel then what it means that kernel execution started  and cpu can process further code or cpu block until it is finished completely on GPU.

Comment: Please read the specification, it is pretty clear on that. `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is non-blocking and will execute on a device sooner or later if not requesting immediate action with `clFlush`. In the mean time, you can use the CPU for whatever purpose you like. But, you will _never_ see the behaviour of `clFinish` if you don't use it, e.g. nothing will block.

Comment: ok sir thanks but if we use same command queue and data is changing regularly  means different batch of data is sending on fixed time interval to GPU and if i dont use clflush so time is (calculated by geteventprofilinginfo) is increased (as cpucode written  increasing after ndqueuerangekarnel) than the time when i use clflush  .....why it is happening sir ?